# SQL Strip Longest Common Prefix

Tags: mysql, sql, string, prefix

I have a table `tbl1` with two columns `col1` and `col2` containing strings:

```
col1    | col2
--------+--------
bar     | foo
foo     | foobar
bar1foo | bar2foo
```

Corresponding SQL dump:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
  `col1` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `col2` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `tbl1` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES
('bar', 'foo'),
('foo', 'foobar'),
('bar1foo', 'bar2foo');
```

The strings of an entry share a common prefix in most cases. I need a query that strips those common prefixes. Expected result:

```
bar  | foo
     | bar
1foo | 2foo
```

My approach, so far:

```
SELECT
SUBSTR(`col1`, 1+GREATEST(LENGTH(`col1`), LENGTH(`col2`)) - CEIL(LENGTH(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM HEX(ABS(CONV(HEX(REVERSE(`col1`)),16,10) - CONV(HEX(REVERSE(`col2`)),16,10)))))/2)),
SUBSTR(`col2`, 1+GREATEST(LENGTH(`col1`), LENGTH(`col2`)) - CEIL(LENGTH(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM HEX(ABS(CONV(HEX(REVERSE(`col1`)),16,10) - CONV(HEX(REVERSE(`col2`)),16,10)))))/2))
FROM tbl1
```

Short explanation: The strings are reversed (`REVERSE`), converted into integers (`HEX` and `CONV`), subtracted from each other (`-` and `ABS`), converted into hexadecimal representation (`HEX`), `0`'s are trimmed from the end (`TRIM`), the length of this result is subtracted from the length of the longest string (`-`, `LENGTH` and `GREATEST`) and then used by `SUBSTR` to get the result.

Problems with my approach:

- Does not work with strings longer than 64bit.
- Does not work with strings containing multi-byte characters
- Very lengthy and ugly
- Does not have good performance.

Comment: This isn't what sql is good at. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the most general and performance method is probably a giant `case` expression.  However, this works only up to a certain length:

```
select substr(col1, prefix_length + 1),
       substr(col2, prefix_length + 1)
from (select tbl1.*,
             (case when left(col1, 10) = left(col2, 10) then 10
                   when left(col1, 9) = left(col2, 9) then 9
                   . . .
                   else 0
              end) as prefix_length
      from tbl1
     ) t;
```

Actually, you can do this with a recursive CTE, which is the most general approach:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select col1, col2, 1 as lev, col1 as orig_col1, col2 as orig_col2
      from tbl1
      union all
      select substr(col1, 2), substr(col2, 2), lev + 1, orig_col1, orig_col2
      from cte
      where left(col1, 1) = left(col2, 1)
     )
select col1, col2
from (select cte.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by orig_col1, orig_col2 order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

Although the performance will definitely be worse than your solution or the massive `case` expression, it is probably not that bad, and you might find it sufficient for your purposes.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df317ec5e7c5e1cba55089553941bf2e) is a db<>fiddle with both solutions.

Comment: I accepted your answer since it provides a solution for strings of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 1):

This code works, although it's *lengthy and ugly* and (maybe) *unperformant*:

```
select 
  substring(t.col1, g.maxlen + 1) col1, 
  substring(t.col2, g.maxlen + 1) col2
from tbl1 t inner join (
  select t.col1, t.col2,
    max(case when left(col1, tt.n) = left(col2, tt.n) then tt.n else 0 end) maxlen
  from tbl1 t inner join (
    select 1 n union all select 2 union all  select 3 union all  select 4 union all 
    select 5 union all  select 6 union all  select 7 union all  select 8 union all  
    select 9 union all  select 10 union all  select 11 union all  select 12 union all 
    select 13 union all  select 14 union all  select 15 union all  select 16 union all 
    select 17 union all  select 18 union all  select 19 union all  select 20
  ) tt on least(length(t.col1), length(t.col2)) >= tt.n 
  group by t.col1, t.col2
) g on g.col1 = t.col1 and g.col2 = t.col2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55Dpr53hQAnrzaz2j2ECz3/2).
For **MySql 8.0+** you can use a `recursive CTE` and in this case there is no need of prior knowledge of the length of the columns:

```
with 
  recursive lengths as (
    select 1 n
    union all
    select n + 1
    from lengths
    where n < (select max(least(length(col1), length(col2))) from tbl1)
  ),
  cte as (
    select t.col1, t.col2,
      max(case when left(col1, l.n) = left(col2, l.n) then l.n else 0 end) maxlen
    from tbl1 t inner join lengths l      
    on least(length(t.col1), length(t.col2)) >= l.n 
    group by t.col1, t.col2                                
  )  
select 
  substring(t.col1, c.maxlen + 1) col1, 
  substring(t.col2, c.maxlen + 1) col2
from tbl1 t inner join cte c 
on c.col1 = t.col1 and c.col2 = t.col2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8mAZj1EPkw9nPai3nYdrWZ/0).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
|      | bar  |
| bar  | foo  |
| 1foo | 2foo |
```

Comment: For this solution one needs to know the strings' length a priori. However, it works for me. Thanks!